# Plotting white for zero value in R

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have a rasterstack

```
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 47, 89, 4183, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent     : 60.75, 105.25, 15.75, 39.25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
names      :    VegC.1,   layer.1,    VegC.2,   layer.2,    VegC.3,   layer.3 
min values :   0.00000, -11.52596,   0.00000, -11.51896,   0.00000, -11.49996 
max values :  21.14100,  16.52118,  18.85200,  16.69225,  23.08900,  20.25300
```

I plot the stack with same color scheme. However I want the 0 value to be white. i use the colorscheme

```
cols <- inlmisc::GetColors(scheme = "BuRd",n = 256)
```

But the plot shows blue on the zero value. Is there an easy way for fixing color scale for raster stacks?

Answer (score 0):

I answer based on the following assumptions:

- You are using the `raster` package
- You are using the `plot()` function of the `raster` package to generate the plot

*(next time, please indicate both the packages and the functions you are using, and even better, provide code with a reproducible example --it doesn't have to be based on your data, just a small dataset that you can use to show your problem)*

Most of the times your (very natural!) wish of mapping the zero value to the middle of the palette --even if the data are not symmetric around zero-- is fulfilled by using a parameter in the plotting function. See for instance this post on the `pheatmap()` function where the `breaks` parameter is used:
[Set 0-point for pheatmap in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677923/set-0-point-for-pheatmap-in-r)

That said, from the documentation of the `plot()` function of the `raster` package we see that it accepts a `...` parameter which can receive any parameter that is accepted by the `image.plot()` function of the `fields` package, as indicated in the Details section of the `plot()` function:

> **Details**
>   Most of the code for the plot function for a single Raster* object was taken from image.plot (fields package).")

In the documentation of the `image.plot()` function of the `fields` package we read:

> breaks Break points in sorted order to indicate the intervals for assigning the colors.
>   Note that if there are nlevel colors there should be (nlevel+1) breakpoints. If
>   breaks is not specified (nlevel+1) equally spaced breaks are created where the
>   first and last bin have their midpoints at the minimum and maximum values in z
>   or at zlim

You can read the answer for [Set 0-point for pheatmap in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677923/set-0-point-for-pheatmap-in-r) on how to set the breaks so that the 0 value is mapped to the middle of the color palette you chose (i.e. white).

Note: I cannot give you a working example because I don't have the `raster` package installed.